# How to add control over invoking of methods in existing sub classes without modifying the sub classes?

Tags: java, class, methods

I have some `BaseClass` with some method `void doSomething()`.

There are different ways to `foSomething` and they are implemented by `SubClass1`, `SubClass2` and `SubClass3`.

Now I want to add a `Boolean active` property to the `BaseClass` so that when `doSomething` is called on an instance it will just return without doing anything.

I know I can code the `BaseClass` to have `doSomething()` that looks something like:

```
Void doSomething(){
   if (this.getActive()) actuallyDoSomething();
}
```

And then `@Override actuallyDoSomething()`  instead of `@Override doSomething()` in the subclasses.
but it feels wrong... in the sense that It has already been agreed that the subclasses should provide an implementation for `doSomething()` and they are not aware of `actuallyDoSomething()`.

I also can have each sub class add an `if (!this.getActive()) return;` at the beginning of its implementation of `doSomething()` but this also seems wrong as its common functionality that I would prefer to keep common.

What is the common/best practice way to do this?
Can it be done without changing the sub classes?

**Update**

The focus of the Q is not about the right way to design such functionality (which is quite simple), 
but on how such functionality can be **added** to an existing scenario without breaking anything.

`active` would be true by default, but it is desired that on any instance of any the said sub classes if someone would call `setActive(false)` then it will become inactive and consecutive calls to `.doSomething()` will not do anything...

Comment: Make `ActuallyDoSomething()` `abstract` and `protected` in your base class. Have it implemented in the child classes. `DoSomething()` should possibly be `final`. In Java, follow Java naming conventions.

Comment: So the intention is to have this functionality of setting the `active` flag in ALL classes - also in the derived ones? If this is the case, then the solution suggested by Sotirios Delimanolis seems the most appropriate. Otherwise, depending on the actual intention, you might consider some "Wrapper" class that delegates the call only when the flag is set - like `if (active) delegate.doSomething()`

Comment: Changed the letter casing of my methods (sorry for that). 
Working with abstract protected `actuallyDoSomething()` is a good idea if this is the way things are being planned to begin with...
My Q is about changing an existing situation. (maybe the answer remains the same)... is there no reasonable way to do this 1) without introducing changing the classes? 2) Without introducing a new and different method? What would you do if you had tens or hundreds of sub classes for the BaseClass? will you hvae to change all of them? and all the code that already uses them?

Comment: @epeleg Because of polymorphism, you can't force a call on a sub class object to go through the parent's implementation first. There will be considerable changes to do. You can minimize them by first refactoring the method name of `doSomething()` to `actuallyDoSomething()` and then just change the parent class by adding a new `doSomething()` method.

Comment: @Alex, I am not familiar enough with Aspect Oriented Programming, and not sure I understand how to use your comment.

Comment: I have posted a (long) answer describing in depth how you can add the feature without breaking anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `@Around` advice from AspectJ and do something like this:

```
// Let subClass instances run normally...
cec.setActive(true);
letThemDoSomething("BEFORE", sbc1, sbc2, sbc3);

// Now change existing scenario...
cec.setActive(false);
letThemDoSomething("AFTER", sbc1, sbc2, sbc3);
```

This will output:

```
BEFORE ======
SubClass1: doSomething() called.
SubClass2: doSomething() called.
SubClass3: doSomething() called.

AFTER ======
Blocking instance<1> method: my.first.spring.aop.aspectj.SubClassN#doSomething([]) !!
Blocking instance<2> method: my.first.spring.aop.aspectj.SubClassN#doSomething([]) !!
Blocking instance<3> method: my.first.spring.aop.aspectj.SubClassN#doSomething([]) !!
```

In the following lines, I'll describe how to make this happen with the annotation.
I will also use Spring here. It helps making the configuration quickier and easier.

---

### 1- Configuration

**Tools and dependencies**

Java 7, AspectJ 1.7.4, Spring 4.0.2

**Project structure**

[image: AspectJ Around advice sample code - project structure]

**pom.xml**

```
<project ...>

  <properties>
     <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target> 

     <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
     <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

### 2 - Existing code

**BaseClass.java**

```
public class BaseClass {
    public void doSomething() {

    }

    public void say(String msg) {
         System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

**SubClassN.java**

```
public class SubClassN extends BaseClass {
    private Integer index;

    public SubClassN(Integer index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        say("SubClass" + index + ": doSomething() called.");
    }

    public Integer getIndex() {
        return index;
    }
}
```

### 3 - Change existing code (without breaking anything...)

Here comes AspectJ and its @Around advice. We'll first ask AsjectJ to call a *particular method* when any `doSomething` method is invoked. `doSomething` can be anywhere in the `BaseClass` or in any of its child class.

This *particular method* is called `changeExistingScenario`. It can have any name. The important here is the annotation placed on it.

A word about the @Around value:

> execution(* my.first.spring.aop.aspectj.BaseClass.doSomething(..))

This expression simply indicates the method signature pattern we want to intercept.
It will intercept any doSomething method in BaseClass or child class no matter
how many parameters, return type and access modifier.

For more details see: http://guptavikas.wordpress.com/2010/04/15/aspectj-pointcut-expressions/

**ChangeExistingCode.java**

```
@Aspect // Mark ChangeExistingCode as the class for modifying the code 
@Component
public class ChangeExistingCode {
    private boolean active;

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    /**
     *
     * This method will be called by AspectJ anytime a `doSomething` method is called.
     *
     * This will give us a chance to decide whether the `doSomething` method should
     * be called or not.
     *
     */
    @Around("execution(* my.first.spring.aop.aspectj.BaseClass.doSomething(..))")
    public void changeExistingScenario(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        // Is active ?
        if (active) { // Yes, let doSomething() run as usual
            joinPoint.proceed();
        } else {// No, block doSomething() invokation
            Signature s = joinPoint.getSignature();

            System.out.format( //
                    "Blocking instance<%d> method: %s#%s(%s) !!\n", //
                    ((SubClassN)joinPoint.getTarget()).getIndex(), //
                    s.getDeclaringTypeName(), //
                    s.getName(), //
                    Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()) //
                    );
        }
    }
}
```

### 4- Let's all the magic appear...

**Main.java**

```
@Configuration // Mark the Main class as the class where Spring will find its configuration
@ComponentScan // Ask Spring to look for other components within the Main class package
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy // Let Spring auto configure AspectJ aspects for us...
public class Main {

    private static int subClassCounter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        subClassCounter=0;

        GenericApplicationContext  context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Main.class);

        SubClassN sbc1 = context.getBean(SubClassN.class);
        SubClassN sbc2 = context.getBean(SubClassN.class);
        SubClassN sbc3 = context.getBean(SubClassN.class);

        ChangeExistingCode cec = context.getBean(ChangeExistingCode.class);

        // Let subClass instances run normally...
        cec.setActive(true);
        letThemDoSomething("BEFORE", sbc1, sbc2, sbc3);

        // Now change existing scenario...
        cec.setActive(false);
        letThemDoSomething("AFTER", sbc1, sbc2, sbc3);

        context.close();
    }

    private static void letThemDoSomething(String prefix, SubClassN... existingClasses) {
        System.out.format("%s ======\n", prefix);
        for (SubClassN subClassInstance : existingClasses) {
            subClassInstance.doSomething();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    @Bean // Tell Spring to use this method for creating SubClassN instances
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE) // Scope prototype force creation of multiple instances
    private static SubClassN buildSubClassN() {
        subClassCounter++;
        return new SubClassN(subClassCounter);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
BEFORE ======
SubClass1: doSomething() called.
SubClass2: doSomething() called.
SubClass3: doSomething() called.

AFTER ======
Blocking instance<1> method: my.first.spring.aop.aspectj.SubClassN#doSomething([]) !!
Blocking instance<2> method: my.first.spring.aop.aspectj.SubClassN#doSomething([]) !!
Blocking instance<3> method: my.first.spring.aop.aspectj.SubClassN#doSomething([]) !!
```

### 5- References

- > Download full code: http://www.filedropper.com/advicearoundsample
- > [AspectJ official site](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj)
  >
  > - [@Around javadoc](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/aspectj5rt-api/index.html?org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Around.html)
  > - [@Aspect javadoc](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/aspectj5rt-api/index.html?org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Aspect.html)
- > [Spring official site](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/)
  >
  > - [@Bean javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html)
  > - [@Component javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html)
  > - [@ComponentScan javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)
  > - [@Configuration javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)
  > - [@EnableAspectJAutoProxy javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html)
- > Other useful resources that helped writing this answer
  >
  > - [AspectJ Pointcut Expressions](http://guptavikas.wordpress.com/2010/04/15/aspectj-pointcut-expressions/)
  > - [Mkyong - Spring AOP + AspectJ annotation example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/)

Comment: Hi Alex,
First I want to thank you for a very well written answer. It was very interesting to read and can probably help others. unfortunately I can not use that as I am using Java 6, and not using spring. and even if this was not the case it is a bit of an over kill for me right now to add this. That said I will still accept your answer because of its high quality and I will add another answer describing what I ended up doing myself.

Comment: @epeleg The solution is compatible with Java 6. Just change `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` to 1.6. It is possible to use AspectJ without Spring. This will incur more work for setting up everything.

Comment: @epeleg  Here is the full source code as a convenience: http://www.filedropper.com/advicearoundsample

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but maybe you're searching for the **template method** design pattern.
Pls see:
http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html

or just search for the pattern with google, there are very nice sites about it.
Hope I could help.

Comment: It does not help either because it again requires that I know in advance that I want to have this feature...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the update section in your question. With that I would say decorator pattern (open-closed princilpe) around your base class where you implement this new feature as Marco13 mentioned. But of course nicer soultions may came up.

Answer (score 1):

So what I though I would do is the following:

Add to the base class a new signature for `doSomething`

```
public final void doSomthing(boolean testBeforeDoing, ..../*original params*/) {
   if (!testBeforeDoing || this.getIsActive()) {
         doSomething(..../*original params*/)
   }
}
```

and

```
public void doSomething(..../*original params*/) {}
```

and of course add support for `isActive` in the base class.

so now any old code that used to call `doSomething` on the base class or any subclass with the old signature would still run the same (i.e. ignoring the active/inactive state of the instance.

Any code that wants to use the new ability to deactivate an instance can call `.setIsActive(bool)` and add `true` as the first parameter to any call he makes to `doSomething`.

This way i get the following advantages:
1) Backwards compatibility
2) no changes required on sub classes at all
3) minimal changes when wanting to use the new functionality

But this way has some limitations, 
for example if `doSomething` already had 2 signatures that differ by one boolean at the start then this does not work.

i.e. if I had `doSomething(boolean b,int i)` and `doSomething(boolean a,boolean b,int i)`
than adding a `bool testBeforeDoing` to the first signature would result in `doSomething(boolean testBeforeDoing,boolean b,int i)` which is indistinguishable from `doSomething(boolean a,boolean b,int i)` and thus can not be done.

So what I ended up doing is the following:

Instead of adding the `boolean testBeforeDoing` I will just add a `doSomthingIfItCanBeDone` to the based class.. and have it call `doSomething()` if it knows that `someThingCanBeDone()` and all the above advantages remain without the disadvantage.

so

```
public final void doSomthingIfItCanBeDone(..../*original params*/) {
   if (this.someThingCanBeDone()) {
         doSomething(..../*original params*/)
   }
}

public boolean someThingCanBeDone() {
  return this.isActive();
}
```

and of course add support for `isActive` in the base class.

Note that this way `someThingCanBeDone()` can also be overridden by sub classes to supply additional limitations on when doSomething can be called and when it can not.

```
@Override
public boolean someThingCanBeDone() {
  return base.someThingCanBeDone() && someConditionLocalToTheSubclass;
}
```